# Prometheus alert manager template changes

Tags: go, prometheus

I have prometheus alert manager running with a template, and im getting email subject as following

> [FIRING:6] Unusual network throughput out (thanos group_b aws_us_b
>   instance_191 infrastructure monitoring-prometheus-node warning)

all the values after the alert name are labels.
here is the template subject code

```
{{ define "__subject" }}[{{ .Status | toUpper }} {{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{ end }}]  {{ .GroupLabels.SortedPairs.Values | join " " }}  {{ if gt (len .CommonLabels) (len .GroupLabels) }} ({{ with .CommonLabels.Remove .GroupLabels.Names }}   {{ .Values | join " " }}   {{ end }}) {{ end }}{{ end }}
```

I would like to modify this only to get following

[FIRING:6] Unusual network throughput out (group_b instance_191)
only group name and instance name

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace your template with something like this:

```
{{ define "__subject" }}[{{ .Status | toUpper }} {{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{ end }}] {{ .GroupLabels.alertname }} ({{ .GroupLabels.group }} {{ .GroupLabels.instance }})
```

Not sure what will happen if the `group` or `instance` labels are not common across all alerts (e.g. if you have an alert firing across multiple groups and/or instances). Maybe you'll just get an empty string, maybe `null`. According to some [brief testing in the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tK0vmtHA2Ga), it would seem you may get `<no value>`. If you don't want that, you can play around with [Go template's `{{if }}` action](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions).

Something like

```
{{ if .GroupLabels.group }}{{ .GroupLabels.group }}{{ end }}
```

Comment: those labels are common across all alerts. works perfect